# Passing values from Fit tables to services where the passed value has prefixes / suffixes of multiple spaces

Tags: fitnesse

I am using FitNesse to test services and specifying the input parameters for the services in table cells Fit tables; in some instances I have test cases where I need to pass in a string parameter value that has a suffix / prefix of several space characters.

When I edit the tables I see the spaces i.e. 'my test value     ' but when I save the table and view the table the value looks like it has been trimmed to have only a single space i.e. 'my test value '.

The question is, can I get around this somehow so that I can pass values from Fit tables into tests with prefixes / suffixes of multiple spaces?

Answer (score 1):

This is part of the fact that FitNesse is a wiki and web based system.  HTML tends to ignore redundant whitespace.  In many situations, FitNesse performs a strip to ensure that this web behavior doesn't cause false positives.

The option I would recommend first is that you define a placeholder character that would be substituted inside your fixture code for a space character.  This would allow you to have those characters and keep them.

Comment: That would work fine and is minimal work in the fixtures, Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using fitSharp you can wrap the whitespace in quotes: "  my test  "